# How to Show result which posted before 3 hours only

Tags: php, ios

I am using below mentioned code to show locations in UITableView via PHP and MySql.I need to show only the locations which is posted before 3 hours only. These locations posted by users and listed in UITableView as I said.

Her is my Select:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT *,
        ( 6371 * acos( 
        cos(radians(%s)) * cos(radians(lati)) * 
        cos(radians(longi) - radians(%s)) + 
        sin(radians(%s)) * sin(radians(lati)) 
        ) ) AS distance
        FROM `markers`
        HAVING distance < 100              
        ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100",
    mysql_real_escape_string($lati), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($longi),  
    mysql_real_escape_string($lati));
```

My table has (date and time), Is there any way to show the locations which posted before 3 hours from the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find recent records use `HAVING` and `INTERVAL # interval_units` of the timestamp column.

So in your case providing the "date and time" column is named `post_timestamp` would the query be like:

`AND post_timestamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR)`

So it takes the column with timestamp, in this example `post_timestamp` where having the value more or equal to `NOW()` or up to previous `INTERVAL 3 HOURS` .

Updated full query:

```
SELECT *, post_timestamp,
    ( 6371 * acos( 
    cos(radians(%s)) * cos(radians(lati)) * 
    cos(radians(longi) - radians(%s)) + 
    sin(radians(%s)) * sin(radians(lati)) 
    ) ) AS distance
    FROM `markers`
    HAVING distance < 100 
    AND post_timestamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
    ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/73767)**

**[MySQL Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)**

Comment: I have updated my answer with query fix and link to demo.